# How do I bind a URL parameter with a period in it to an MVC action parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

A web browser is calling my action with the following URL;

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4000/MyController/UrlCheck?Menu.Url=sometext
```

My action is as follows;

```
public JsonResult UrlCheck(string Url)
{
    return Json("Url is " + Url , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But the Url parameter never gets bound, I've tried the following to no avail;

```
public JsonResult UrlCheck([Bind(Prefix="Menu")] string Url)
```

The URL is generated by MVC itself as part of an Ajax post and is tied to a property of a complex object, hence the 'Menu.Url' bit. It won't be easy to change the name of the URL parameter.

Have also tried Menu_Url as a parmeter name. The action is executed so the routing should be working fine.

Comment: Have you tried instead to bind to your complex object, e.g., `public JsonResult UrlCheck(MyComplexObject Menu)`? You should then be able to check Menu.Url.

Comment: That might have worked, but the complex object, is well complex and a simpler hack is what @Charlino suggested below. Both similar approaches, so thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't come across binding get parameters like that, but I would try binding to a simple viewmodel that is named `Menu` and has a property called `Url`.

E.g.

**Your Viewmodel**

```
public class SimpleViewModel
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

**Your Action**

```
public JsonResult UrlCheck(SimpleViewModel Menu)
{
    return Json("Url is " + Menu.Url, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```